# Is there a way to increase upload speed in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, upload, find, adsl

I don't know why my upload speed is so poor. I use adsl connection, and I measured the speed using cable, not wireless. However, the speed is still poor and I was wondering if there is something I could do in terminal in order to improve the speed. I tried to clear cache, browsing history etc., but it's still the same.. Any ideas? I also tried this http://www.ubuntumanual.org/posts/10/how-to-increase-internet-speed-in-ubuntu
But I get the message "command not found". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The internet is composed of a chain of computers between you and the host server that contains the file you are downloading. Your upload speed is the slowest of all these links. Some sites are always slow, and some sites just get slow during local peak hours.

Either find another site that's faster, or just be patient. Also, for many ISPs, the upload speed is much slower than download, as uploads are not done as often as downloads. When you buy an ISP connection, they advertise the faster, download speed, as that is what matters to most people. Call your ISP to see what your actual upload speed should be.